# docker stop command not working correctly

Tags: docker

What is the real purpose of `docker stop` command?!! After a system reboot, I tried to stop all the docker containers and it says no error about that.  But, I see all containers again! See this output

```
mahmood@orca:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
a95c13863461        780bd4494e2f        "/bin/sh -c 'apt-get "   20 hours ago        Exited (137) 20 hours ago                       pensive_banach
54a3b132af8c        3d4b41a3842f        "/bin/sh -c ''/root/s"   22 hours ago        Exited (137) 21 hours ago                       master
ea413e092330        1049eef389d5        "/entrypoint.sh -t 4 "   8 days ago          Created                                         dc-server
03917ffb3f44        edac12b8dc40        "/bin/sh -c 'cd $MAHO"   8 days ago          Exited (137) 8 days ago                         sick_snyder
b64958d95615        aaea9c6a8dc9        "/bin/sh -c 'cd $MAHO"   9 days ago          Exited (1) 9 days ago                           compassionate_turing
8ad0f235a48b        4a793e47ece4        "/bin/bash"              9 days ago          Created                                         data
mahmood@orca:~$ docker stop a95c13863461 54a3b132af8c ea413e092330 03917ffb3f44 b64958d95615 8ad0f235a48b
a95c13863461
54a3b132af8c
ea413e092330
03917ffb3f44
b64958d95615
8ad0f235a48b
mahmood@orca:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
a95c13863461        780bd4494e2f        "/bin/sh -c 'apt-get "   20 hours ago        Exited (137) 20 hours ago                       pensive_banach
54a3b132af8c        3d4b41a3842f        "/bin/sh -c ''/root/s"   22 hours ago        Exited (137) 21 hours ago                       master
ea413e092330        1049eef389d5        "/entrypoint.sh -t 4 "   8 days ago          Created                                         dc-server
03917ffb3f44        edac12b8dc40        "/bin/sh -c 'cd $MAHO"   8 days ago          Exited (137) 8 days ago                         sick_snyder
b64958d95615        aaea9c6a8dc9        "/bin/sh -c 'cd $MAHO"   9 days ago          Exited (1) 9 days ago                           compassionate_turing
8ad0f235a48b        4a793e47ece4        "/bin/bash"              9 days ago          Created                                         data
mahmood@orca:~$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation:

> -a, --all             Show all containers (default shows just running)

You are seeing all containers (stopped and active), type `docker ps` to see only active ones.